# How to autowired 2.x Spring cloud openFeign interface when my spring Cloud version is Edgware.RELEASE ? Spring can't find this bean

Tags: java, spring-cloud, feign

My colleague offers me a openFeign interface which is based in spring Cloud 2.x, i can't inject it in my service as usuall. (my spring cloud version is Edgware.RELEASE, and may be it may be the initiator of this problem),so what can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Edgware is incompatible with Boot 2.x

Answer (score 0):

As @spencergibb has mentioned in his comment, Edgeware is not compatible with Spring Boot 2.x.  You will need to use the Finchley release train:

Please read the Release Train section of the [Spring Cloud Documentation.](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud)

Comment: Probably more than that, if you'e still using Edgware then I am going to make a guess that you're also still on Spring Boot 1.5.x.